# The Integral with Inverse Tan

Tags: calculus

Can

$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$$ not be integrated as

$$\dfrac{\ln (x^2+1)}{2x}$$ ?

If I reverse it, with chain rule and everything, it goes back to $\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$.

How does it become $\arctan (x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you missed the point that the quotient $\frac{1}{2x}$ also needs to be differentiated in the chain rule.

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2x} = \frac{1}{2x} \frac{2x} {x^2 + 1} - \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{4x^2} = \frac{1} {x^2 + 1} - \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{4x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Way $1$ :

$y=\tan^{-1}x \quad \implies \tan y=x \quad \implies \sec^2 y \dfrac{dy}{dx}=1 \quad \implies (1+(\tan(\tan^{-1}x))^2)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1 \quad \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2},$

So that anti derivative of $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}is \tan^{-1}x$.

Way $2$ :

$\int\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}dx$.  Substitute $x=\tan u$ so,$\quad$ $dx=\sec^2u du$

$\int \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\int \dfrac{\sec^2u}{\tan^2 u+1}du=\int \dfrac{\sec^2u}{\sec^2u}du=\int du=u+c_1=\tan^{-1}(x)+c_1$